# Help me to understand a solve of example that I have homework correctly

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Write each set, using the list method
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B68B.png)

[image]

$a) A\setminus B=\{a,b,c,d\},$

$b) A\setminus (B\cup C)=\{a,b,c\}$

$c) A\cap(B\cup C)=\{1,2,d\}$

$d) (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)=\{1,2,4,6,a,b,c,d\}$

$e) A\cap\ B\cap C=\{1\}$

$f) (A\cup B\cup C)'=\{7,8\}$

$g) (A\cap B)\setminus C=\{2\}$

$h)A\setminus (A\cup B)=\langle\text{no number}\rangle$

[2] Find the number of subset of the set $A=\{\text{letters in GEOMETRY}\}$

Answer: $A=\{G,E,O,M,T,R,Y\}, n(A)=7\Rightarrow n(P(A))=2^7=128$

Is my anwers correct. Help me to conclude

Comment: d) is incorrect.

Comment: d) {\1,2,d} (i thinks now is correct), is it [2] correct

Comment: a Can anyone confirm that my answers to [1] and [2] is correct

Comment: What is $[1]$? 2 is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Part (d) of [1] is incorrect: $A\cap B=\{1,2\}$, and $A\cap C=\{1,d\}$, so

$$(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)=\{1,2\}\cup\{1,d\}=\{1,2,d\}\;.$$

Note that you can actually deduce this from your correct answer to (c): one of the distributive laws says that

$$(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)=A\cap(B\cup C)\;.$$

The correct answer to (h) is the empty set, written $\varnothing$ or, if list form is required here as well, $\{\}$.

Everything else is correct.